# How to use log4j in code?

Tags: java, singleton, log4j

We have to introduce logging in our application. We have decided to use log4j is it a good choice. Also somebody told that we should use singleton pattern for using log4j can somebody emphasise how and why?

Comment: Consider slf4j instead of log4j.

Comment: what is slf4j? How is it different..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are introducing logging for the first time then use Logback. Use the configuration file as [suggested here](http://logback.qos.ch/faq.html#configFileLocation)  and add it to the classpath. Logging will be auto configured.

Comment: Why have you mentioned if for first time. How is it helpful firsttime.

Comment: Some people are stuck with log4j even though the world had advanced ;-). Introducing a better alternative is really hard once you have something working and the team is comfortable with it. So it is better to do your due diligence and find a better alternative when introducing new framework/technology. How look here to find out why Logback is better: http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html

Answer (score 6):

In the singleton pattern, the `Logger` field is static to the class:

```
public class SomeAwesomeClass {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SomeAwesomeClass.class);

}
```

The alternative is to make the `Logger` field non-static (that is, each instance of `SomeAwesomeClass` holds a reference to the `Logger`):

```
public class SomeAwesomeClass {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SomeAwesomeClass.class);

}
```

I don't think it makes a lot of difference which route you choose as I believe Log4j will continually return the same `Logger` instance for each instance of `SomeAwesomeClass`. Really, it's just unnecessary object references, so you might as well use the singleton pattern.

**However**, the non-singleton pattern becomes necessary if you do something like this:

```
public class SomeAwesomeClass {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    public void doSomething() {
        log.info("Doing something");
    }

}

public class AwesomerClass extends SomeAwesomeClass {
}
```

Later...

```
SomeAwesomeClass o = new AwesomerClass();
o.doSomething();
```

In this example, the `logger` field will correspond to `AwesomerClass`, not `SomeAwesomeClass`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why Singleton is sometimes preferable is that we want only one instance of the Logger **per application**, otherwise, for every new instance of the logger, there will be a newly created file or an overwrite of an existing log file.

As to whether Log4J is a good choice or not will depend on your research/experience with the different loggers available. It's all about your preference (I use Log4J all the time as I find it easier to configure, but I'm not biased to any loggers out there).

Famous ones out there are:

- Log4J
- SLF4J
- LogBack
- Java's own Logging....

There are some examples on the web that shows you how to use loggers. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLF4J) is a brief comparison for Log4J vs SLF4J.